# Drawing Boxes in PDF::Reuse

Tags: pdf, rgb, catalyst, template-toolkit

I am looking for more examples or documentation for drawing boxes using PDF::Reuse.

I would like to be able to:
1. Draw a box with no fill so that text can be printed inside the box. (Is this possible?)
2. Draw a shaded box with no border and text.
3. Reset text color to black after drawing a colored box.
4. More consistently control RGB colors.

I am using Template::Toolkit along with Catalyst::View::PDF::Reuse. Withing PDF::Reuse I am using the prAdd function.

Here is an example where I can draw a box with a black border, however, the text does not show when placed in the same x y location as the box. I assume it is being "painted" over.

[% pdf.prText(90,600,'black text above box','right') %]
[% pdf.prText(90,550,'black text inside box','right') %]

[% box = '255 .5 1 rg 20 550 70 30 re b' %]
[% pdf.prAdd(box) %]

Among the specific questions I have are:
1. What do the "rg" and "re" parameters do and what are other possible values?
2. Is there a unique chart or list of RGB values for the application?

The developer seems to indicate Adobe documentation for more help, but the listed page may not be up to date.

Thanks in advance for any directions

Comment: Did you try first drawing the box and then the text?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I tried that but doing so also raises another issue: how to change text color back to black or a default color. After your message I retested to confirm that that is not the solution. Text appears to either side of the box and the box appears to print on top of the text.

Comment: Progress. I am now able to print text in a shaded box by wrapping the box parameters with 'q' and 'Q'. Apparently this tells the application to save and restore the Graphic State.

Per @Jongware comment, you do have to print the text after printing the box.

[% box = 'q 101 0 0 rg 20 550 70 30 re b Q' %][% pdf.prAdd(box) %]
[% pdf.prText(90,570,'black text above box','right') %]

Comment: `rg`: _Each operand must be a number between 0.0 (minimum intensity) and 1.0 (maximum intensity)._ [link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved most of the issues in my first question, though I am still guessing at some of the specific PDF operators and variable values.

I am now able to draw a shaded box with no border and text.

The solution to the box and text I explained above in my comment.

The solution to turning of the border can be found (through trial and error) in the appendix to this PDF reference http://www.verypdf.com/document/pdf-format-reference/pg_0986.htm.

A box is drawn around a rectangle when you follow the "re" operator with a "b" operator. (B means closepath, fill, stroke)

A shaded rectangle is drawn when you follow the "re" operator with an "f" operator.

The following examples in template toolkit will draw red rectangles:

[% box = '1 0 0 rg 20 650 70 30 re b' %][% pdf.prAdd(box) %]

[% box = '1 0 0 rg 20 650 70 30 re f' %][% pdf.prAdd(box) %]